# How can I convert from a bool to an int?

Tags: c#, type-conversion, int, boolean

My code looks like this:

```
if (Settings.adp == true)
   App.DB.UpdateIntSetting(SET.Adp, 0);
else
   App.DB.UpdateIntSetting(SET.Adp, 1);
```

Is there a way I could get this down to one line by somehow converting the bool Settings.adp into an int (0 or 1)

Comment: `App.DB.UpdateIntSetting(SET.Adp, Settings.adp ? 0 : 1)`

Comment: Have a look at this https://www.dotnetperls.com/convert-bool-int

Comment: BTW. `adp == true` `->` `0` which is unusual. I'd put a comment next to this line.

Comment: A note about coding style: nothing says "beginner programmer" like comparing true to true to see if it is true that true is true. The Boolean is already true or false; you don't need to compare it to true to know that true is true.  Just say `if (Settings.adp) …` not `if (Settings.adp == true)`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the ternary operator to consolidate it to one line:

```
App.DB.UpdateIntSetting(SET.Adp, Settings.adp ? 0 : 1);
```

From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator)

> condition ? consequence : alternative

Answer (score 4):

With your reversed logic, Nathan's [ternary operator answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53808682/3181933) is probably the best option for clarity, but you could also use [`Convert.ToInt32`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.toint32?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Convert_ToInt32_System_Boolean_):

```
bool negatedValue = !Settings.adp;
App.DB.UpdateIntSetting(SET.Adp, Convert.ToInt32(negatedValue));
```

[Try it online](https://rextester.com/AMKL66075)

Comment: I guess. I'm wondering why people feel it's a bad answer because of the negated boolean, but that's OP's logic and not mine. Without more information, we can't really comment on OP's design decisions. I'm assuming it's not because people don't realise that `Convert` can do it, considering I linked to the documentation for it.

Comment: When you write code, you need to think of folks like me - who for some reason, do way too much maintenance work these days.  That code makes little sense to a reader.  If you do something like this, surround it by lots of comments.  Better still, use the method shown by @NathanWerry - but surround that with comments too (because of the "true means zero" logic).

Comment: @Flydog57 I guess. Frankly, I noticed the negation after beginning to write the answer. I still felt it was worth demonstrating that `Convert.ToInt32` can achieve converting a boolean to an int. I've edited my answer so that the flow is is clearer for the reader now :)

Comment: But, is `Convert.ToIn32(bool)` really any better than just an assignment with a ternary operator?  In the code I work with, there's often poor use of the ternary operator (making single statements way too long to understand), but, converting from bool to an int in an assignment is the perfect use.  Anyway, thanks for clarifying things (and, no, I didn't downvote you)

Comment: @Flydog I'm not saying it's better. Personally, I'd use the ternary operator in OP's use case, but there was already an answer for that. If it was just a direct true=1/false=0 conversion then I'd probably do it with `Convert`. I added the answer more for future readers. Thank you for your insight :)

Answer (score -1):

Your situation looks like a good candidate for using [ValueObject](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/ValueObject.html), provided that you need to perform that conversion to int in many places in your project.

**Reason:** If you are not using ValueObject you will end up duplicating that logic for conversion to int all over your application. And ValueObject is even more suited for your case because of your inverted logic (true -> 0, false -> 1). Using ValueObject will help you avoid duplication of this logic.

Comment: I'm not a downvoter, but I'm sure this is because you said that this is _"a perfect candidate for using ValueObject"_, but not showing **why this** is _a perfect candidate_. This is the same like sayng _"Your situation looks like a perfect candidate for using <any_design_pattern_name>"_

Comment: @vasily I did say why, didn't I?

Comment: You did say why ValueObject pattern is good, but you don't say why exactly this sample is _"a perfect candidate"_. What if your program is just a 5 lines of code in `Program.Main()` method? Do you think in this case ValueObject is still good?

Comment: Oh I see your point. In such case it is not that very useful. But 5 lines of code, seriously? I mean what can you do with 5 lines of code? I assumed it be some kind of application (notice the words there, App, Db, etc). Anyway I will edit my answer. BTW, thanks for the pointer.

Comment: Sometime, when I will be old enough, I will write a book "The Power of 5 lines of code":)

Comment: WHAT? That's the funniest thing I've heard today (it is still morning here though). :D

Comment: glad you like it:)